# Why my E6 code ${"name"}; isn't working as supposed?

Tags: javascript, string

When I type this code:

```
const name = "Stephen";
document.write("Hey ${name} how are you?");
```

All browser shows:

> Hey ${name} how are you?

instead of:

> Hey Stephen how are you?

What did I do wrong? isn't that E6 feature supposed to work?
I tried Safari, chrome and everywhere it shows the same problem

Comment: It is supposed to work, however, you need backticks (``) for that, not quotes ("").

Comment: You need to use the backtick `\`` instead of quotes `"` to make [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: String interpolation requires the usage of backticks instead of double quotes.  Double quotes are simply ordinary strings.

Comment: @charlietfl This code doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

To use this feature, you have to use backtics:

```js
const name = "Stephen";
document.write(`Hey ${name} how are you?`);
```

Comment: Thank you! lol, those Backtics look extremely similar to single quotation marks. Spent hours trying to figure it out. Thanks!